# Changes doesn't apply to a python module

Tags: python-2.7, python-module

I am relatively new to python. I've started using and completing an under-development python library. However, the changes that I make in the modules don't apply. That is, I debug the code and the list command shows me the initial version of the module. These are the ways that I tried to resolve the problem:

1- restarting the terminal

2- reloading the modules that I had changed using the reload command

The problem still persists. Probably I am missing some basic stuff. 
Also, When I am viewing the files in the module directory, there are two versions of the changed module. for example:

conv.py

conv.py~

I would be grateful if you help me to figure out why this happens and how to apply the changes.

Comment: What editor are you using? Is it possible your changes are being saved only in the file that ends with a tilde?

Also, are pyc files being created when your module is loaded? These are "compiled" Python bytecode files, and are supposed to be regenerated when Python detects the .py file is updated, but perhaps something is going wrong there? If the pyc files exist, you can delete them without harm.

Comment: I am using gedit. I checked the file ends with a tilde and it is the original version of the code. I removed the .pyc files and run the code. Nothing changed ...

Comment: I have a guess about where the problem comes from. Let me know if it makes sense. I have made an instance of a class and stored it in a .pkl file. Then, I changed one of the class functions. The code that I am running gets that .pkl file as its input and calls the changed function for it. It might be the reason. The changes in the class don't apply on the instance of the class that has been made using the previous version!

Comment: That does indeed make sense. There's some discussion at [UsingPickle](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle) about what happens to a pickled object when you change the original class that might be of use.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I figured out the problem roots in using an old .egg file. I install the package again using [code](python setup.py install) command and the .egg file was updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `importlib` for this.

```
import importlib
importlib.reload(my_submodule)
```